# decipher graduation date from diploma

Tags: english, dates

I don't remember the numeric day of the month and year in which I graduated from college. The month was May and the year was 1974. My diploma shows the month, day and year in Latin:

A.D. VIII KAL. IVN. A.D. MCMLXXIV

What is the numeric day?

Answer (score 7):

It's 8 days (a.d. viii) before the 1st of June (kal. iun.). In proper Roman counting, that would be the 25th, since Romans practiced inclusive counting.

However, there's no guarantee your university followed that. If they did,  it's May 25. If they went with the modern system, it would be May 24.

Comment: Thank you - interestingly, I dug and dug and found the date on a document from the university, and the date shows May 26, 1974. Odd...

Comment: @WD Might have been a mistake or a discrepancy, but with inclusively counting May 26th should have been A.D. VII KAL. IVN. [Here's a calendar](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/calendar/juliancalendar.html) so you can see how it's all laid out.

Comment: Thank you - just shows how much more I don't know! Is there a way I can send a jpg to you so you can see it in actual print on the diploma?

Comment: There should be a way to edit your question and include an uploaded image - I think it uploads it to Imgur.

Comment: +1, but note that the way of counting days is part and parcel of the notation, so if they mean May 24, or – *di averruncent* – write something like *a.d. II Kal. …*, they are simply making a mistake.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I agree! My note wasn't meant to indicate they had a legitimate option, but merely that it's possible a mistake was made.